# Can I create Pagination in partial view only in client side, not sending any request to controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pagination, paging, jquery-pagination

In mvc 4 application I have Product search page with `Ajax.BeginForm()` and it returns search result as partial view. In partial view I have product list. Here, how can I create pagination for that list? only with product list, not getting to controller. Because, I dont want to change search criteria. Is it possible?

```
@model IEnumerable<Product>
@{
   List<Product> list;

   if (Model != null)
   {
      list = Model
   }
   else
   {
      list = (List<Product>)ViewBag.AllProduct;
   }

   //products shown here....I want to create Pagination for 'list' in only client
}
```

Comment: yes you can. sending model to html.parial. but you really should use a partial with child action method.

Comment: Yes you can. If you are using custom controls (grids) they all support client side paging, if not code is not much complicated. But seeing your code looks like you've done web forms before, maybe you should take a look at mvc videos on microsoft site..

Comment: Search action returns a partial view. In partial view I do not use grids, show products with foreach loop of list. I should create a Pagination there.